# Write Error in PowerShell when running script

Tags: powershell

When i run my PowerShell script on other computers except for mine (it doesn't always happen on other computers) i get an error that is "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.Log because it is being used by another process." Then it returns a WriteError and IOException.

```
if(Test-Path c:\temp\PMCS_Quick_Test_Ran.txt)
    {
        Remove-Item c:\temp\PMCS_Quick_Test_Ran.txt
    }

Function global:Quick_Test_Run{

Start-Transcript -Path C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.Log

out-file c:\temp\PMCS_Quick_Test_Ran.txt

Function global:LastReboot_Run {

$logstring = "Running Last Reboot Check"
Add-content C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.Log -value $logstring

$os = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem
   $uptime = (Get-Date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))
   $Display = "" + $Uptime.Days + " days, " + $Uptime.Hours + " hours, " + $Uptime.Minutes + " minutes" 
  # Write-Output $Display
   $WPFRebootField.Text="$Display"

if([dateTime]$FiveDaysAgo = (get-date).addDays(-5))

    {
        $WPFRebootField.Background = 'red'
    }

if([datetime]$TwoDaysAgo = (get-date).adddays(-2))

    {
        $WPFRebootField.Background = 'green'
    }

    $logstring = "Date Since Last Reboot = " + $Display
    Add-content C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.Log -value $logstring
    $logstring = "Last Reboot Check Finished"
    Add-content C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.Log -value $logstring
}

LastReboot_Run
```

When the code runs it is supposed to make the file, and as each part completes it outputs the result to PMCS_TicketLogs.Log, but it returns that error. Can anyone clarify why it is returning the error in this particular case? Nothing else is using the file. Thanks.

Comment: Sample is incomplete.

Comment: What else should i put for reference?

Comment: You function scriptblock is never closed or called

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Where do you call `Stop-Transcript`?

Comment: Stop-Transcript is at the very end of my script. It's pretty long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're telling PowerShell to log everything to your log file, so it opens it for reading, but then you're trying to write "Running Last Reboot Check" to the same file, which of course fails because the console has it locked.

If you're always going to be logging to that file, you can just echo it with Write-Output instead and it will be automatically logged by the transcript.